# Calendar overlay across Teams

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams, calendar-view

I'm successfully using a lot of SP-functionality inside Teams. E.g. working with the standard SP-calendar app. I'm frequently using the overlay functionality between different SP-calendars on channels and subsites of a Team.

I tried to do an overlay between two calendars from two separate teams and get the error "Unable to find specified web in the given URL - [https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/teamX"](https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/teamX%22) when I try to add an overlay on a calendar inside contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/teamY.

Why doesn't that work? Is that restriction intentional or not? Of course, those calendars are on different sitecollections if you want to say so. But on the same farm, if one can say that thinking of SP online. How can I circumvent that limitation?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I found out, Microsoft removed the possibility to use calender overlays across site collections when moving to SP online. A lot of people have already complained about this topic, but with little effort.

I will have to code a flow around this limitation which will copy events from calendar to calendar.